# How to do the average and print it for java data structure program

Tags: java

so i have been trying to make my numbers appear however it keeps showing up as zero when i run it. 
I thought i have most of my code right however I do not understand why i keep getting my outcome for the numbers i entered zero , i am using double linked list , also i am fairly new to java.
 this is my constructor and average method 
which both when running keep showing zero

```
 public Student(int id, String  s_name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3, int mark4, int mark5) {
        this.id = id;
        this.s_name = s_name;

    for (int i=1; i<=marks.length; i++ )
    {   
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}

 public  void caculatelAverage() {

      int mark = 0;


        for (int i=0; i<=marks.length; i++ )
        {   

            avg = (10*(marks[i]+marks[i+1]+marks[i+2]/3) + 20*marks[i+3] + 70*marks[i+4])/100;
            this.marks[i]=mark;

        }`
```

marks is

```
private String[] exam_name = new String[5]; // for the 5 exam types
private double avg;
```

lastly I am trying to show this as outcome and the numbers to be calculated for the average

```
Student s1 = new Student(40003, "E", 20, 70, 50, 40, 60);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: It will be difficult to answer this without a [reprex]. How is this.marks being created? What values did you pass in? this.marks=marks does not give us anything to work with

Comment: I'm wondering why do not you get error cause of the overaddressing in `caculatelAverage`

Comment: The marks are being entered when entering a new student each time,Student s1 = new Student(40003, "E", 20, 70, 50, 40, 60); 20,70.... are the marks being entered that are supposed to show up when it runs

Comment: And what is the expected result for the average?

Answer (score 0):

**Please do a minimal research before posting a question in this forum.**

The following can be a solution for you

I have not seen anything like doubly linked list in your code.

Just loop the 5 subject marks for finding total marks. If you divide that total by total number marks then that could be your average.

```
   public class Student {
    int id;
    String s_name;
    int marks[] = new int[5];

    public Student(int id, String s_name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3, int mark4, int mark5) {
        this.id = id;
        this.s_name = s_name;
        marks[0] = mark1;
        marks[1] = mark2;
        marks[2] = mark3;
        marks[3] = mark4;
        marks[4] = mark5;
    }

    public float caculatelAverage() {

        return (10*(marks[0]+marks[1]+marks[2])/3) + 20*marks[3] + 70*marks[4])/100;
    }
}
```

Comment: i need my average formula  to look like this 
 (10*(( A+B+C)/3)+20*D+70*E)/100  would i be able to do that would the formula you have provided?, thanks a lot for your help, also i have a doubly linked class that is too long and couldn't add here

Comment: Yeah you can do it on

Comment: i have tried doing the code you have sent but for some reason all the marks now show up except the average appears as zero what might be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your constructor, I assume that you need to change

```
   for (int i=1; i<=marks.length; i++ )
{   
    this.marks = marks;
}
```

To

```
 this.marks[0] = mark1;
 this.marks[1] = mark2;
 ....
 this.marks[4] = mark5;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot these helped however my average is still not showing what might be the problem ?